# How to add Mozilla ActiveX Control v1.7.12 to my vb.net windows form project

Tags: javascript, html, css, vb.net

I downloaded the mozillacontrol1712.exe file and installed it. It created a new folder in the Program Files (x86) folder...Mozilla ActiveX v1.7.12, containing 14 folders and 169 files. All of the posts said you must register to make it work. I successfully registered the mozctlx.dll file. The tool box shows Mozilla Browser Class. When I try to drag the "control" on to the form it shows a small square and then Visual studio shuts down and starts over with a new blank form. What am I doing wrong? If there is a tutorial out there that would help me get started it would be very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Having had similar problems, may I suggest looking closely at DEP and ensuring all parts of the DLL are excluded?

To research:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/data-execution-prevention

To configure:
https://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-xp/disable-turn-off-dep-windows/